# Data only shows up when I click twice on submit on ReactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm trying to create a link shortener using Reactjs, after I set up the post request for the long URL, I need to display the resulting short URL. The problem is I can't seem to be able to do that. The resulting link only shows up when I click twice on the submit button, but if I refresh the page and click submit, the shortened link does not show up.
I'm hoping you can help me with that, here's my code:

```
import './App.css';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(){
        super()
        this.changelongUrl=this.changelongUrl.bind(this)
        this.onSubmit=this.onSubmit.bind(this)
        this.state={
          longUrl:'',
          shortenedUrl :[],
          urls:[]
        }
      }
      changelongUrl(event){
        this.setState({
          longUrl : event.target.value 
        })
      }
      onSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        const registered={
          longUrl: this.state.longUrl
        }
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/url/shorten',registered)
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/')
          .then(response => {
              this.setState({ urls: response.data });
              console.log(this.state.urls)
          })
          this.setState({
            shortenedUrl: this.state.urls.filter(url => url.longUrl === this.state.longUrl).map(filteredUrl => (
                filteredUrl.shortUrl 
            ))
          })
        console.log(this.state.shortenedUrl)
        this.setState({
          longUrl:''
        })
      }
      render(){
        return( 
        <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} style={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'column'}}>
          <TextField value={this.state.longUrl} onChange={this.changelongUrl}
          style={{ marginBottom: 22 }} className="textfield" id="outlined-basic" 
          label="Please Input Your Link" variant="outlined" />
          <Button style={{
          marginBottom: 22,
          backgroundColor: "#47597E",
          padding: "10px 20px",
          fontSize: "18px"}} 
          variant="contained" type= 'Submit'>Shorten</Button>
          </form>
          <a href={this.state.shortenedUrl}>{this.state.shortenedUrl}</a>
        </header>
      </div>)
       
      }
    }
    
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: It looks like you're calling `axios.get` pretty much simultaneously with `axios.post`, so I'm guessing your backend hasn't created the new shortened link yet. You're going to want to wait for the `axios.post` request to resolve prior to calling `axios.get`.

Comment: Of course, rather than calling `axios.get` again, it's probably worth just returning the shortened link from the `post` request.